# jQuery load() doesn't work on Phonegap Windows Phone 7.5

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, cordova

I write a phonegap application that make use of the jQuery load() function to load content from local files. It works on both iOS and Android, but it doesn't work on Windows Phone 7.5. I've searched for this problem but I can't find a solution anywhere. The problem is that the load() function works in the Windows Phone browser, but not when packaged as a phonegap app.

Here is some example code. 
the index.html-file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> 

        <title>Test</title>

        <script src="scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
        <script src="scripts/functions.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" charset="UTF-8" />

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="#start" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="content" id="start">    
                <div id="text"></div>
                <div data-role="controlgroup">
                    <a href="#bonesida" data-role="button" onClick="test();">Test it!</a>
                </div>
                <div id="text"></div>
            </div><!-- /content -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

the functions.js file:

```
function test() {
    $('#text').load('text.txt');
}
```

the text.txt file:

```
Here's some text.
```

I guess it has something to do with the same origin policy, but this is a local file in the same directory as the other files. Or is it the local URL that's faulty? I also tried to use absolute url (x-wmapp1:/app/www/test.txt) but that didn't work either.

Is it possible to get the load() function to work in a Phonegap app on Windows Phone? What am I doing wrong? I would much appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

use $.get or $.ajax instead :

```
function test(){
 $.get('text.txt', 
        function(data) {
           $("#text").html(data);
        },
        'text');
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, that doesn't work either.

Comment: you can also add a fail callback method to see what's happened : `function test(){
 $.get('text.txt', 
        function(data) {
           $("#text").html(data);
        },
        'text').fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                           alert(xhr.responseText);});
}`

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same problem and I get an error thrown in Files.cs when I attempt to load $('').load('something.html').

Just for kicks I placed the html on a web server that my device has access to and did a $.get on that html resource.  This worked for me.

Unfortunately this isn't a very good answer as I don't want to make a trip out to the www to grab content that already resides on the local device ( not to mention I have this working just great on ios and android).  Hope this helps.

Comment: I have noticed the same thing. Neither do I want to go to a webserver to grab the content. Wierd.